# How Can I Fill the Fields in the CSV File with R When RStudio Appearance Produces 'NA'?

Tags: r, csv

I typed this code

```
library(rtweet)

api_key <- "..."
api_key_secret <- "..."

token <- create_token(
  app="skrip825",
  consumer_key=api_key,
  consumer_secret=api_key_secret
)
dt <- search_tweets("commuterline", n=10000, until='2020-11-02', include_rts=TRUE)
dt

write_as_csv2 <- function(x, file_name,
                          prepend_ids = TRUE,
                          na = "",
                          fileEncoding = "UTF-8") {
  ## to minimize rounding
  op <- options()
  on.exit(options(op))
  options(scipen = 14, digits = 22)
  
  ## validate inputs
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(x), is.character(file_name), length(file_name) == 1L)
  if (!grepl("\\.csv$", file_name)) {
    file_name <- paste0(file_name, ".csv")
  }
  ## flatten data
  x <- flatten(x)
  if (prepend_ids) {
    x <- prepend_ids(x)
  }
  utils::write.table(file_name, row.names = FALSE, na = na,
                     fileEncoding = fileEncoding, sep=";", qmethod="double")
  
  # or
  # readr::write_csv(x, file_name)
}
environment(write_as_csv2) <- asNamespace("rtweet")

producethedata <- write_as_csv2(dt,"crlll.csv")

lapply(producethedata,function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

The output of dt after I clicked it from environment in RStudio.

[image: Output of dt]

and output of CSV File after I runned that code

[image: Output of CSV File]

I want to fill the fields that are 'NA' in RStudio. Give me correction from that code. Thank you for your aid.

Comment: `NA` means "not available", this is an R way of saying "this is empty". It is not exactly clear what behavior do you expect from writing the CSV file.

Comment: Hello Hil and welcome ... 
First question - what do you want to fill the NA fields with? 
Second remark 
`write.table(file_name, row.names = FALSE, na = na, ...`  
causes you to have `na = ''` since you defined that as the default for the `write_as_csv2` function in its parameters. So if you provide the `na` parameter to YOUR function it should fill it with that value when writing.